# Swift. Remember a facebook login

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-login

Okay so I have implemented a facebook login button:

```
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
loginButton.center = (self.view?.center)!

loginButton.delegate = self

self.view?.addSubview(loginButton)
```

but every time I shut down the app completely and turn it on again I need to rejoin, so my question is how an I make the app remember that I've already logged in once?

Answer (score 1):

try using this

Put this code in your appDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    //user is sign in
  //Put here something what you want to do if user is sign in

}

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

save the email or facebook token which you get from the facebook response in your Userdefaults or coredata..

then check for the value first in the login screen and direct your app..